# Manipulating columns of a dataframe based on a name match in a separate dataframe

Tags: r, string-matching, data-wrangling

I am looking to find a way to use a data frame that has two columns (the first one being the name, and the other being numerical values), and if a name matches with that of a column below (DF1), then to keep that column.

For example, I have a data frame called List1:

| Group | Number |
| --- | --- |
| group1 | 0.5 |
| group3 | 0.6 |
| group4 | 0.8 |
| group5 | 0.9 |

I want to compare the strings in the first column of List1, and if one of the entries in that column matches with a column name in DF1 (exception is I want to keep the first two columns of DF1 regardless), and if there is a name match between List1$Group and a column name, then to keep it in DF1.

I have this DF1:

| Name | Key | group1 | group2 | group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XAS /// HUA | test1234 | 10 | 10 | 8 |
| MPA1 /// AAS2 | test4553 | 8 | 7 | 4 |
| MPAS | test3341 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| SSPA1 | test2142 | 5 | 6 | 8 |
| MAS61A | test4722 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

So the goal is to get this new data frame after applying the code (group 2 is dropped because it is not in List1):

| Name | Key | group1 | group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XAS /// HUA | test1234 | 10 | 8 |
| MPA1 /// AAS2 | test4553 | 8 | 4 |
| MPAS | test3341 | 5 | 5 |
| SSPA1 | test2142 | 5 | 8 |
| MAS61A | test4722 | 6 | 4 |

How can this be done for large data sets? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

```
# DF1
Name <- c("XAS /// HUA", "MPA1 /// AAS2", "MPAS", "SSPA1", "MAS61A")
Key <- c("test1234", "test4553", "test3341", "test2142", "test4722")
group1 <- c(10, 8, 5, 5, 6)
group2 <- c(10, 7, 5, 6, 7)
group3 <- c(8, 4, 5, 8, 4)
DF1 <- data.frame(Name, Key, group1, group2, group3)

Group <- c("group1", "group3", "group4", "group5")
Number <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9)
List1 <- data.frame(Group, Number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%in%` operator to compare two sets of strings.

#### Solution 1

Since you want to keep the first two columns, we need to set the logical values to `TRUE` (i.e. `c(TRUE, TRUE)`) so that they will be kept.

```
DF1[, c(TRUE, TRUE, colnames(DF1)[-c(1:2)] %in% List1$Group)]
```

---

#### Solution 2

Or `cbind` the first two columns after matching for the `group` columns.

```
cbind(DF1[,1:2], DF1[,colnames(DF1) %in% List1$Group])
```

---

#### Output

```
           Name      Key group1 group3
1   XAS /// HUA test1234     10      8
2 MPA1 /// AAS2 test4553      8      4
3          MPAS test3341      5      5
4         SSPA1 test2142      5      8
5        MAS61A test4722      6      4
```

Comment: A similar variant might be `. <- names(DF1); DF1[. %in% c(.[1:2], Group)]` or `DF1[names(DF1) %in% c(names(DF1)[1:2], Group)]`